# mysql random select Latest 15 in 100 rows data

Tags: php, mysql, random

```
$sql = "SELECT `url`,`title`,`vid` FROM `video` ORDER BY `time` DESC limit 15";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This SQL can select the top new 15 rows data.

I want display the top new 100, but just show 15

How to select faster?

Comment: When you make a LIMIT on 15 you get only 15 ;) so whats the problem?

Comment: I need in the Latest 100 , show 15 random. how to change the sql?

Comment: If you want the query to run faster, have a look at the explain plan and see if you can make it more efficient through the right indexes or even a data restructure.

Comment: once you need to get last 100 items, then with another query select 15 random items.

Comment: I know order by rand() , but so slow.

Comment: do not use `order by rand()` its a load on the mysql. Select last 100 records using `order by time DESC limit 100`, use PHP code to get the random 15 records from the result set.

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty is right. You Use shuffle() function to randomize array comming from SQL query

Comment: SELECT url, title, vid FROM (SELECT url, title, vid, time, rand() as r FROM video ORDER BY r LIMIT 100) ORDER BY time LIMIT 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT `url`,`title`,`vid` FROM `video` ORDER BY `time` DESC limit 100";
```

i assume that `$row[0]` => gives first record.

--

```
function UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange($min, $max, $quantity) {
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
}
```

--

```
foreach (UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange(0,100,15) as $row_number)
{
   $content=$row[$row_number];
   echo $content['title'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could try fixing it like:

```
<?php
//get the max count for the table;
$max="SELECT id FROM video order by time desc LIMIT 1";
$start="SELECT id FROM video order by time desc LIMIT 100, 1";
$page_size=15;
$rand_no=rand(start,$max - page_size);

$result_set="SELECT * FROM video order by time LIMIT $rand_no,page_size";
```

**NB**: it's an abstract code explains the logic.

Comment: Thanks so much for your demo. Your idea is a good other choose